# Leaflet library not avaliable even though it's in sites/all/libraries

Tags: javascript

I've seen people talking about hook_library() etc., but I'm not creating a custom module, I'm trying to use Leaflet. In the browser I get the error message:

```
L is not defined
```

From leaflet.drupal.js in my sites/all/modules folder. I've got the Leaflet and Libraries modules installed and enabled, and the Leaflet files are extracted under sites/all/libraries/leaflet.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the library hasn't been installed correctly, the path should be `sites/all/libraries/leaflet/leaflet.js` you should be able to append this to your sites URL to load the file.

Have you looked through https://www.drupal.org/node/1954942 to see whether anything helps?

Comment: Appending that to the site loads the file (at least I've not screwed up 100% then I guess!). I want to use the library at www.mywebaddress.com/map, so maybe that's the problem? But the libraries folder is under sites/all, so that shouldn't be the case I guess, hmm

Comment: Anything helpful in the console?

Comment: When I access the js file from browser? The only thing I get is
"The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature."

Comment: No when trying to access a page and you get L is not defined

Comment: Ah, no, that's all I get, unfortunately! I tried replacing my leaflet.js (which is the dist version) with the source code version, but I got the same error message!

Comment: I think the problem might be that the leaflet files doesn't actually get LOADED into the site, even though they're in the sites/all/libraries folder. Any idea how I can make that happen?

Comment: The leaflet module gets loaded, but not the leaflet.js from sites/all/libraries (according to the Network tab of the Firefox dev tools)! How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you add `drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/leaflet/leaflet.js');`?

Comment: To where? All I've done for the site is strictly through Drupal and it's already made functionality, so I haven't written any code for it (hence I don't know where I should put it)

Comment: OK let's take a step back, how have you added the Leaflet map to your site? What mechanism are you using to display a map?

Comment: A view with an attachment that is of the format "Map (Leaflet API, via IPGV&M)". I've followed this guide quite thoroughly http://www.chenhuijing.com/blog/drupal-101-mapping-with-leaflet-and-ipgeoloc/

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, on the status report of a site where I have it installed says Leaflet 0.7.3 The Leaflet Javascript library is installed correctly. One map available.

Comment: Might it have something to do with the installation of the Libraries module?

Comment: In my working site I have the format set to Leaflet Map rather than Map (Leaflet API, via IPGV&M) does that help?

Comment: When I change it to that I get "$menu.on is not a function" from sites/all/themes/multipurpose/js/plugins.js

Comment: If I just put it to Geofield Map I get a standard google maps map to show, so that's something! But I guess that doesn't let me show the nodes I want to show on it!

Comment: Now after changing it back I just get the "$menu.on is not a function" from sites/all/themes/multipurpose/js/plugins.js error message!